# How can I add a title attribute to wp admin menu?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, attributes, set, attr

I am trying to do this programmatically in my WP plugin.

From this `<div class="wp-menu-name">Dashboard</div>`.

To this `<div class="wp-menu-name" title="My New Title">Dashboard</div>`.
I've tried it from my js file, tried different action and filter hooks and nothing works. Here's the latest version of my code.

```
function tooltip_hook(){
     
   return ?> 
<script>

      jQuery(div).ready(function ($) {
          //this is what was in my js file and I decided to try it this way. No luck!
         $( "#menu-dashboard" ).attr( "title", "My New Title" ); //set title attribute 
         
     } );
   } );
      </script>';
      <?php
  }
  add_filter( 'admin_menu', 'tooltip_hook' );
```

I've also tried setting the item: option in .tooltip but couldn't figure out how to use it. I'm a beginner as js.

If anyone can help me accomplish adding tooltips to my Admin menu, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using id `#menu-dashboard` to find element in jQuery. But you don't have id in you element `<div class="wp-menu-name">Dashboard</div>`

Either you can assign id to your div tag `<div id="menu-dashboard" class="wp-menu-name">Dashboard</div>`

Or you can find your element using class in jQuery `$( ".wp-menu-name" ).attr( "title", "My New Title" );`

Comment: Thanks. This is the id WP has assigned to the menu item. I use it for other functions. In fact, it works for .tooltips in the following function. 
`$( '#menu-dashboard' ).tooltip(   );`
The problem is, without a title, it can't output a tooltip. When I add a title in the Inspect window, the tooltip works perfectly.

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle for it?

Comment: I haven't used it before, but here's my best.. :)
https://jsfiddle.net/deshinab/z0ht2fxn/11/#&togetherjs=6O3NxJNBBU

Comment: I checked. It's not working because you have a lot of console errors. so your jquery code never gets to execute. try to fix those errors first.

Comment: Thanks @Vahida Vadiya